# Rails: Storing static data like ActiveRecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, static, storage

I've been looking for a while for gems and/or plugins that implement static storage similar ActiveRecords but is not database-based.  Let's call this class NonDBRecord.  It should have the following property:

```
class Foo < NonDBRecord
  add_item('a', :property1 => 'some value', :property2 => 'some more value')
  add_item('b', :property1 => 'some value', :property2 => 'some more value')
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to_nondbrecord :foo, :class_name => 'Foo'
end

# NonDBRecord declare constants automatically
[ Foo::A, Foo::B ]

# NonDBRecord is enumerable
Foo.all # returns [Foo::A,Foo::B]

# NonDBRecord is id-based
Bar.create(:foo_id => Foo::A.id)

# ...so you can search by it
x = Bar.find(:first, :conditions => { :foo_id => Foo::A.id })

# ...and is stored, retrieved, and instantiated by its id
x.foo # returns Foo::A
```

I've thought about simply using ActiveRecords (and database storage), but I don't feel good about it.  Plus I've had to tip-toe around some eager loading problems with the ActiveRecord solution.  Any help would be appreciated before I start writing my own solution.

*edit*

These records are meant to be enumerations.  For example, let's say you're making a card game.  I want to be able to do something like

```
class Card < NonDBRecord
  attr_reader :suit, :index
end
class Game
  belongs_to :wild_card, :class_name => 'Card'
end
```

Comment: Where would you store your data?

Comment: If you are averse to setting up a using database instance, how about sqlite? Gives you a file on disk.

Comment: @Toby: that would be in memory.  See edit in post.

Comment: @garrow: not averse to databases, but i just don't think it's the right usage.  have you ever had database columns for a constant, enumerable type?  see edit in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say ActiveModel is what you are looking for. It comes with Rails 3 and encapsulates all kind of goodies from ActiveRecord, such as Validation, Serialization and sorts. There is a Ryan Bates [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) on that issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did this work for you? If so it would be nice to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

As BigD says, ActiveModel is the Rails 3 way.

In Rails 2.3 I am using this as a kluge:

```
class TablelessModel < ActiveRecord::Base  
  def self.columns() @columns ||= []; end 

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true) 
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null) 
  end

  def save(validate = true) 
     validate ? valid? : true 
  end
end
```

I use that to e.g. validate contact forms that are not going to persist in any way. It's possible it could be extended for your specific purposes.